# Angular 2/Named Router outlet : Load a diffferent component when route param is available

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am developing a meal planner with a screen for recipes.

Functionality:
The screen displays a list of item names and an initial text ('Select a recipe to view details here')
Once a recipe is clicked, the details are displayed on the right.

Please view screen setup here

[image]

What I have:

(1) Initially http://domain/mealplanner/(recipes:recipes) is loaded to display list of recipes. - Works correctly

(2) Once a recipe is clicked, the url changes to http://domain/mealplanner/(recipes:recipes/0).
I expect the RecipeDetail component to be added, but it is not loaded.

The code:

recipes.routing.module.ts

```
const recipesRoutes : Routes = [
    {path:'mealplanner', children : [
        {path:'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, outlet : 'recipes', children: [
            {path:':recipeId', component: RecipeDetailComponent} ]}  -----------------------------> What should I add here to make it work?
    ]}
];
```

Inside recipe-item.component.ts

```
export class RecipeItemComponent {
    
    @Input() recipeId: number;
    
    onItemSelect() : void {
        this.router.navigate(['mealplanner','recipes',recipeId]);
    }
}
```

Please note: I will have to use only named outlets since I have to add a shopping list to this screen later.

Thank you for your time, and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the router outlet tag in RecipesComponent HTML?

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: yes, I added <router-outlet name="recipes"></router-outlet>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. As Mohammed Babaei suggested, in recipes.component.html, I added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to get to work.